# How can I automatically connect to a VPN if I connect to a specific Wi-Fi network on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, vpn, ipsec, on-demand

I have set up an IKEv2 VPN connection with Windows 10. How can I automatically connect to this VPN if my laptop connects to a specific Wi-Fi network?

Comment: Do you have programming skills?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if you have tried using something like this before, but it is the way I have set this feature up, and it seems to work just fine...

https://www.ibvpn.com/billing/knowledgebase/270/Set-up-the-IKEv2-using-Automatic-VPN.html